# Can the stand in a Mid-2011 21.5" iMac be removed?

Tags: imac, hardware

I have a mid-2011 21.5" iMac (EMC 2389) and I am trying to remove the stand. I'm trying to follow [this guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IjnAEnPmbEg) but I can't seem to find the "latch" that he talks about. I heard that any iMac past 2011 doesn't have a removable stand; this is a 2011 model. Is the stand even removable (whether or not in this manner) and if so how would I go about doing it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

iFixIt.com have some of the best step-by-step guides for repairs on just about any Apple device.

I found their guide for removing the stand of your iMac here:
https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/iMac+Intel+21.5-Inch+EMC+2389+Stand+Replacement/113471

I see it as a little bonus that it's based on steps - that way you don't have to pause the video multiple times.

Good luck!